# Is it ok to store GA4 api_secret on the frontend?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am trying to add Analytics to my chrome extension and for that I am following [1]. Everything works locally but I am not sure if its safe for me to actually deploy my extension.

Anyone could inspect the source files or the network requests and with that have access to my `secret_api`. Now, I know that the only way around this is having this store on my server, however I do not get from the documentation whether this is an actual secret or not, however:

1. The name makes is very obvious that this is an actual secret.
2. G4A documentation says this key should not be disclosed.

If the above is true, why does the documentation in [1] and Google's own example in [2] is storing it in the frontend?

Does someone know whether this is actually sensitive or not and what one would be able to do with it? (besides spamming my analytics).

[1] https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/tut_analytics/

[2] https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/blob/main/functional-samples/tutorial.google-analytics/scripts/google-analytics.js

Answer (score 2):

As a Chrome extension runs client-side, it's probably very difficult if possible at all to keep the API secret a secret. Even if you manage to somehow obfuscate it, a user can use the extension debugging tools to take a look at the actual network call, which includes the API secret in plaintext.

The worst thing somebody can do with it is to spam your Analytics property, as you mention. In the [Measurement Protocol's documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/reference?client_type=gtag#payload), Google somewhat indifferently recommends to rotate the API secret regularly to "avoid excessive spam".